# Can a verb in the -ing form take a direct object?

Tags: grammar, infinitives

Here is the example:

> We condemn such behavior that can risk damaging a company’s brand and reputation.

I think, the 'a company's brand reputation' is the object of 'damaging'. And the whole phrase is the object of 'risk'. is it right?

Comment: The title of your question isn't quite clear; could you edit? I'm not quite sure how *transitive verb [for] an object* quite relates to the final question in the body.

Comment: A nit: the combination of "such behavior that..." doesn't sound natural to me. I suggest dropping the word "such".

Comment: Agree with JSBangs: "such" is a specifier which does not allow another specifier such as a restrictive relative clause. It would be OK with a commenting relative clause (comma before "that").

Comment: @JSBangs @Jimi Oke  I mean 'must', a transitive verb must follow an object. When it be used as a gerund, is it still need to follow an object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your analysis of the sentence is correct. The -ing form is a *present participle*, which can take a direct object, in this case "a company's brand and reputation". The participle + object acts as the complement of the verb "risk".

Comment: Thank you, JSBangs! I ever think that the participle+object acts as object. so, what's the difference between object and complement? why you think it as a complement, not object?

Comment: I think this is a gerund phrase rather than a participial phrase. An example of participial use may be, "I saw him damaging the company's reputation." (Please correct me if I'm wrong.) The gerund+object combination acts as the object of the verb _risk_.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me, but I do not think the participial phrase would be  "I saw him damaging the company's reputation." It may be this way: "I saw HIS damaging OF the company's reputation." because in "I saw him damaging the company's reputation", damaging's function is not an adjective but a verb. I may be wrong, if so anyone who has an explanation can post it, so everyone can be clarified! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for your comment - but you have posted this as a new answer, whereas it is actually just a comment on the existing answer, plus a new question. I appreciate that you do not have enough reputation to post a comment, but you could create a completely new question, incorporating the relevant parts of the previous answer and your query about them.